# Migrating to new Linux RHEL host/server -- error 150 when moving folders

Tags: permissions, ftp, linux, file-permissions

I've just began migration of my website to a new host. The server is Linux RHEL and I have SSH access as well as Plesk for control panel admin.

I've uploaded my files via FTP using Panic's Coda. The files are compressed as folder.tar.gz and uploaded to the httpdocs directory in the new server.

The I extracted the folder via SSH. On SSH and Coda I can see the extracted folder and the files it contains.
But when I try to save, move or delete any of these files via Coda I get

`Error 150: could not rename remote file`

Permissions for both the uploaded folder and httpdocs is `755`.

If I do a `rm -r -f` via SSH then I can delete. Otherwise, anything I do via FTP/Coda causes the above error.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see if ACLs are in use.

Comment: when I do `ls -l html` (html is the decompressed folder) I see no `+` adjacent to the permissions -- does that confirm NO ACLs are in use?